# Как ограничить столбец?

Tags: mysql

Например, есть значение Age. Как сделать чтобы в его столбце число не могло быть меньше 0?

Answer (score 1):

Для подобного рода ограничения можно использовать [`TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) перед добавлением в таблицу. В Вашем случае подойдёт что-то в этом роде:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS age_limit;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER age_limit 
BEFORE INSERT ON `test`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.age < 0) THEN
        CALL `Error: invalid age`;
    END IF;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

[Пример на DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nM69ZhcYJdF996JXREPmS6/0).